# Is it safe to remove extra interface languages?

Tags: macos, macbook

MacReviver is suggesting I remove most interface languages to clean up 198 MB in my MacBook Air to speed it up.  Should I do it?  Will it affect any other program adversely?

Answer (score 0):

Some apps don't mind, others will break; some signed apps don't recognise their own signature.

At your own risk.

For the sake of 200 MB I'd leave it alone.